# What disorder does the Riddler have in Gotham?

Tags: character, analysis, gotham

I'm curious as to what disorder Ed Nygma has from Gotham. I know he has OCD from the comics but I'm talking about how his Riddler persona appears to and interacts with him. Something that caught my eye is how the Riddler persona can "interact", for lack of a better word, with the world around Ed.

I'm talking about the scene in Gotham 4x17 when he visits Penguin in Arkham and holds up the letter showing the secret code. Ed's too stupid to have realized the code, but The Riddler figured it out and highlighted it for him. This means he is subconsciously super intelligent via the Riddler. If he has DID, can one identity surpass the intellectual capabilities of another, because I assumed all of them would be confined to the same cognitive function?

So does he have DID, schizophrenia, or just straight up insanity?

Comment: My money’s on DID as the most plausible. On a more opinionated note, I feel like Nigma’s character was done very well in that series and C M Smith NAILED it.